# Only one value returning from array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use chartjs in my MVC ASP.net application. I am trying to populate an array from values in my model. However, when I display my array only 1 value is being shown. Below is my view snipped with the code in question. When I debug the application I can see 77 record iterating through my foreach loop. Why am I only getting one data point returned in my chart?

```
var dollars = [];
    @foreach(var item in Model.OrderBy(m => m.TimeReceived))
    {
        @:dollars.push('@item.startingDollars')
    }

  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['Dollars'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dollars',
        data: dollars,
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I only getting one data point returned in my chart?

The `data: { labels: ['Dollars'] ... }` property in your code is listing only one entry in the array.

The `chart.js` documentation states the following:

> If the labels property of the main data property is used, it has to contain the same amount of elements as the dataset with the most values. These labels are used to label the index axis (default x axes). The values for the labels have to be provided in an array.

Set the `labels` property in your code to an array. The sample below sets the `labels` property to the time received data.

### Reducing HTML output size generated by Razor and sent to client

The `foreach` iterator in your Razor view produces output similar to the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Orders.OrderBy(m => m.TimeReceived))
{
    @:dollars.push('@item.StartingDollars');
}
```

HTML output

```
const dollars = [];

dollars.push('12');
dollars.push('10');
dollars.push('15');
```

Your post stated 77 records. The `foreach` iterator generates `dollars.push('x');` 77 times, adding a lot of extra HTML output sent to the client browser.

The output can be simplified using `Linq` so that the size of the HTML output sent from the server to the client is significantly reduced:

```
@{
    // Razor Syntax: Razor code block to declare 'orderedQuery' variable
    IEnumerable<Order> orderedQuery = Model.Orders.OrderBy(m => m.TimeReceived);
}
const dollarsArr = @Json.Serialize(orderedQuery.Select(i => i.StartingDollars));
```

HTML output:

```
const dollarsArr = [12,10,15];
```

### Sample

```
<h3>Starting Dollars and Time Received Chart</h3>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#razor-code-blocks

        const dollars = [];
        const timeReceived = [];

        // Razor Syntax: Explicit line transition
        @foreach (var item in Model.Orders.OrderBy(m => m.TimeReceived))
        {
            @:dollars.push('@item.StartingDollars');
            @:timeReceived.push('@item.TimeReceived');
        }

        @{
            // Razor Syntax: Razor code block to declare 'orderedQuery' variable
            IEnumerable<Order> orderedQuery = Model.Orders.OrderBy(m => m.TimeReceived);
        }
        const dollarsArr = @Json.Serialize(orderedQuery.Select(i => i.StartingDollars));
        const timeReceivedArr = @Json.Serialize(orderedQuery.Select(i => i.TimeReceived.ToString("MMMM d yyyy")));

        // chart.js installation
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html
        // https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/chart.js?path=dist

        // Line chart
        // https://www.w3schools.com/ai/ai_chartjs.asp
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html
        // https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#data-structures

        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: timeReceivedArr,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Dollars',
                    data: dollarsArr,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

The sample code produces the following chart:

[image]